# Memory use growing forever with RoboBrowser?

Tags: python-2.7, memory-management, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, robobrowser

[**EDITED** to simplify the example/isolate the problem better]

Using `RoboBrowser` with multiple subsequent visits to the same URL causes memory to grow with each visit, even when you re-initialise and overwrite the original `RoboBrowser` instance each time. This goes against my intuition for how memory management works in Python and I want to understand why.

To demonstrate this here's a memory profile for a script that visits https://news.ycombinator.com/ask and gets all divs (I deliberately made this repetitive so the memory profile is more complete):

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     5   19.684 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     6                             def scrape():
     7
     8   19.684 MiB    0.000 MiB       url='https://news.ycombinator.com/ask'
     9
    10   19.719 MiB    0.035 MiB       browser = RoboBrowser(parser="html.parser", history=0)
    11   25.102 MiB    5.383 MiB       browser.open(url)
    12   26.598 MiB    1.496 MiB       browser.find_all('div')
    13
    14   26.602 MiB    0.004 MiB       time.sleep(1)
    15
                                       # re-initialising the browser doesn't free up memory:
    16   26.609 MiB    0.008 MiB       browser = RoboBrowser(parser="html.parser", history=0)
    17   27.535 MiB    0.926 MiB       browser.open(url)
    18   27.859 MiB    0.324 MiB       browser.find_all('div')
    19
                                       # also doesn't free up memory:
    20   27.859 MiB    0.000 MiB       browser = None
```

Here's a different script that works as I expect:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     5   20.102 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     6                             def make_string():
     7   20.148 MiB    0.000 MiB       a = 'a'*1000000
     8   21.109 MiB    0.961 MiB       a = a + 'a'
     9   20.148 MiB   -0.961 MiB       a = None        # memory usage drops as expected
```

Why when scraping does the allocated memory just keep piling up? What should I look into to understand this problem better?

I'm generating the scraping memory profile by running `python -m memory_profiler mem_test.py` using Python 2.7.6

Full script for `mem_test.py`:

import time
    import memory_profiler
    from robobrowser.browser import RoboBrowser

```
@profile
def scrape():

    url='https://news.ycombinator.com/ask'

    browser = RoboBrowser(parser="html.parser", history=0)
    browser.open(url)
    browser.find_all('div')

    time.sleep(1)

    browser = RoboBrowser(parser="html.parser", history=0)
    browser.open(url)
    browser.find_all('div')

    browser = None

if __name__=='__main__':
    scrape()
```